# Why do backticks work for highlighting code in Discord, but Armenian commas don't?

Tags: special-characters

When I send code in Discord using this:

````
```py
print("hello world!")
```
````

it appears in a box with code highlighted as you can see in the picture below. However, when I use Unicode U+055d ([Armenian comma](https://codepoints.net/U+055D)) for the code fences (`՝՝՝ ՝՝՝`) :

```
՝՝՝py
print("hello world!")
՝՝՝
```

and send it, the code doesn't get highlighted. It also does not appear in the box as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Comment: For more info, in Unicode these are called "confusables" and there's tons of them. Here's an [official demo page](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/confusables.jsp?a=%60&r=None). Some others are `ˋ`‵｀`. My favorites are the Cyrillic letters like `а` and `р` cause they look *exactly* like the Latin letters in most fonts.

Comment: Is there any application where Armenian commas do work for formatting code? Why would they?

Comment: If you press `ALT-96` in windows, you get a backtick, which has an ascii code of 96, or 60 hex; not an armenian comma.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I faced the same thing when I edited your question. This:

````
```py
print("hello world!")
```
````

renders as:

```py
print("hello world!")
```

whereas this:

```
՝՝՝py
print("hello world!")
՝՝՝
```

renders as:

՝՝՝py
print("hello world!")
՝՝՝

While the characters for designating code fences are similar to the eye, they are different for your apps. The backtick character (`` ` ``) has the Unicode representation of U+0060, while the Armenian comma (`՝`) has the Unicode representation of U+055D, as you said.

The code formatting here and in Discord uses some flavor of [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/), for which backtick U+0060 characters have a special meaning (are used for highlighting code), while the Armenian comma U+055D character has no special meaning. That makes your text correctly highlighted when using backticks and printed just as you wrote it when using Armenian commas.

Comment: There is a visible difference between backtick and Armenian comma. Edit: - on this device (PC, chrome, win11). Your mileage may differ.

Comment: It depends on the font used and the font rendering. When I see this thread from my phone, the difference is clear. However, when I read it from my PC, both look almost the same.